# Python : How to read pickle dump?

Tags: python, sql, pickle

I have a pickle dump which I got from a friend and he asked me to read it like :

```
f = open('file.pickle')
import pickle
l = pickle.loads(f.read())
```

But I get an `ImportError` saying `no module named sql.models`

Can someone help me understand what is happening ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the code required to reconstruct the pickled objects.

Pickles store the location where the class can be imported from, together with the instance attributes. The original module is still required to recreate the module. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully qualified” name reference, not by value. This means that only the function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised. [[4]](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#id14)
>
> Similarly, classes are pickled by named reference, so the same restrictions in the unpickling environment apply. Note that none of the class’s code or data is pickled, so in the following example the class attribute `attr` is not restored in the unpickling environment:
>
> ```
> class Foo:
>     attr = 'a class attr'
>
> picklestring = pickle.dumps(Foo)
> ```
>
> These restrictions are why picklable functions and classes must be defined in the top level of a module.

In other words, the original data used to *create* the pickle includes at least one instance of a custom class that originates in a module named `sql.models`.

Do be careful reading arbitrary pickles, even from friends. A pickle is just a stack language that recreates arbitrary Python structures. You can construct a pickle that spawns a secret back-door server on your computer, with enough determination and skill. The `pickle` documention warns you explicitly:

> **Warning**: The `pickle` module is not intended to be secure against erroneous or maliciously constructed data. Never unpickle data received from an untrusted or unauthenticated source.

This has [been a problem in the past](http://www.zopatista.com/plone/2007/11/09/one-cookie-please/), even for experienced developers.

Comment: Do I need to write those classes ?

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi: I'd ask your friend for the code; you won't be able to reconstruct the original class from the pickle alone.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I doubt he would like to set a backdoor to my system :P but I'd be careful :D